What are the solutions of $y^{(n)}= \omega y$ for naturals $n\geq 3$ and $\omega$ a primitive $n^{th}$ root of unity
$\sin$ and $\cos$ form a nice basis for the solutions of $y''= -y$, so I am wondering what are the solutions of $y'''= j y$ and generally $y^{(n)}= \omega y$ ?

I suggest the ansatz $y(t)=e^{at}$.

Because it's a homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients, it can be solved via its characteristic equation.
We can look at the first DE and use that as a way to understand what the general solution will look like. The characteristic equation comes from testing the Ansatz solution $y = A \exp(\lambda x)$. Substituting that into the DE gives
$$\begin{eqnarray} y''' & = & j y \\
A\lambda^3 \exp(\lambda x) & = & j A \exp(\lambda x) \\
(\lambda^3 - j) A \exp(\lambda x) & = & 0 \\
\implies \lambda^3 - j & = & 0
\end{eqnarray}$$
So $\lambda$ must be a complex cube root of $j$. If we write $j = \exp\left(\frac{j \pi}{2}\right)$, then its cube roots are $\lambda_k = \exp\left(\frac{j \pi}{6} + \frac{2 j k \pi}{3}\right)$ for $k = 0, 1, 2$. With reference to Euler's formula and some basic trig identities, we find $\lambda = \pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} + \frac{j}{2}, -j$.
Having found these roots, the general solution to the DE is given by $y = A_0 \exp(\lambda_0 x) + A_1 \exp(\lambda_1 x) + A_2 \exp(\lambda_2 x)$, i.e. the solutions can be formed from a basis of $\{\exp(\lambda_k x)\}$.

Thank you. I was wondering if we can find a nicer way to write the solutions. I mean some other 3 functions which can be the basis of the vector space of solutions. Like the sin and cos for $y''=-y$

It depends on what you mean by "nice". You can express $e^{(a + jb)x} = e^{ax}(\cos bx + j \sin bx)$ and then do a change of basis so that you get everything as products of exponentials and trig functions, but there's only so much you can do especially when the coefficients in your original DE are already complex.
